# The Cloned Quote record is taking the currency of user instead of taking the currency of parent Quote?

Tags: configuration, cpq, quote, multi-currency, currency

We are using a standard Clone feature for a Conga Quote object in Conga CPQ. When cloning instead of the Quote's currency the currency of the user is filled. We don't want that behavior we want it to fill with the original quote currency. How do we do it ?
Actual Quote
[image]

Cloned Quote
[image]